# Why is `fixed_auto_queue_size` in Elasticsearch deprecated?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to configure the threadpool of my Elasticsearch cluster. The [`fixed_auto_queue_size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-threadpool.html#:%7E:text=Deprecated%20in%207.7.&text=The%20experimental%20fixed_auto_queue_size%20thread%20pool,will%20be%20removed%20in%208.0.) looks a neat idea as it adjusts its maximum queue size based on Little's Law. However, this feature is deprecated in ES 7.7.0. Does anyone know why the feature is deprecated? I'm interested in practical issues that this configuration will have. Is it because Little's Law assumes a stable system? If so, what could go wrong when the assumption is not true any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the [details of this change](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/52280), the two given reasons were that:

- the two `fixed_auto_queue_size` thread pools (`search` and `search_throttled`) were not configuring this dynamic adjustment
- Elastic was not aware of any user making use of this dynamic setting

Since the feature was experimental and they didn't get much feedback on it, they decided to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, Val. May I know where the PR shows that `search` pool were not configuring the adjustment? [The lines 303 to 308](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/52280/commits/5f9055f1337144983a7be5bdf2ef17db29cdf7d1#diff-9f5585442c620397550df0ceb9faf151e8042e3c7444254ebf562153073c1d3fL303-L308) appear to indicate that `search` did use `fixed_auto_queue_size` if it is configured.

Comment: You can see it in the [initial comment](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/52280#issue-564169229)

Comment: Yeah, I'm puzzled by the initial comment, as the code implies that the auto adjusted queue was [the only default](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/52280/files#diff-2835e151b1e7435ff4760a9263e0ecbc359597a9ff02005fc7fec099d38549e6L170)